# Rails_admin gem on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rubygems, rails-admin

I'm trying to run a project using the rails_admin gem on heroku, but get the following error when performing assets:precompile:

```
remote:        I, [2015-11-12T23:13:37.913854 #908]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_be9e6f7c3fc8b833cd6ab95c29eeb71b/public/assets/rails_admin/base/mixins-3e0cccbb54e2038718c2b538a370d24f.css
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$navbar-height".
remote:        (in /tmp/build_be9e6f7c3fc8b833cd6ab95c29eeb71b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/r    ails_admin-0.7.0/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/base/theming.scss:16)
```

And then:

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems you have a syntax error with your SASS

```
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$navbar-height".
remote:        (in /tmp/build_be9e6f7c3fc8b833cd6ab95c29eeb71b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/r    ails_admin-0.7.0/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/base/theming.scss:16)
```

Take a look at your `theming.scss` file at row `16`

Sort your syntax error out and you will resolve your error